# How to make gallery float on left and right side?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am stuck as I can't get the items to align next to each other. So for example instead of 8 down.

I want to make it 4 on the right side and 4 on the left side.

```js
  $(function() {
    // there's the gallery and the trash
    var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
      $trash = $("#trash");

    // let the gallery items be draggable
    $("li", $gallery).draggable({
      cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
      revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
      containment: "document",
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "move"
    });

    // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
    $trash.droppable({
      accept: "#gallery > li",
      activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        deleteImage(ui.draggable);
      }
    });

    // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
    $gallery.droppable({
      accept: "#trash li",
      activeClass: "custom-state-active",
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        recycleImage(ui.draggable);
      }
    });

    // image deletion function
    var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";

    function deleteImage($item) {
      $item.fadeOut(function() {
        var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ?
          $("ul", $trash) :
          $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);

        $item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
        $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
          $item
            .animate({
              width: "48px"
            })
            .find("img")
            .animate({
              height: "36px"
            });
        });
      });
    }

    // image recycle function
    var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";

    function recycleImage($item) {
      $item.fadeOut(function() {
        $item
          .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
          .remove()
          .end()
          .css("width", "96px")
          .append(trash_icon)
          .find("img")
          .css("height", "72px")
          .end()
          .appendTo($gallery)
          .fadeIn();
      });
    }

    // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
    function viewLargerImage($link) {
      var src = $link.attr("href"),
        title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
        $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");

      if ($modal.length) {
        $modal.dialog("open");
      } else {
        var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
          .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
        setTimeout(function() {
          img.dialog({
            title: title,
            width: 400,
            modal: true
          });
        }, 1);
      }
    }

    // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
    $("ul.gallery > li").click(function(event) {
      var $item = $(this),
        $target = $(event.target);

      if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
        deleteImage($item);
      } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
        viewLargerImage($target);
      } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
        recycleImage($item);
      }

      return false;
    });
  });
```

```css
  #gallery {
    float: left;
    width: 6%;
    min-height: 12em;
  }
  .gallery.custom-state-active {
    background: #eee;
  }
  .gallery li {
    float: left;
    width: 96px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .gallery li h5 {
    margin: 0 0 0.4em;
    cursor: move;
  }
  .gallery li a {
    float: right;
  }
  .gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin {
    float: left;
  }
  .gallery li img {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: move;
  }
  #trash {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 18em;
    padding: 1%;
  }
  #trash h4 {
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 0.4em;
  }
  #trash h4 .ui-icon {
    float: left;
  }
  #trash .gallery h5 {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">

  <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras_min.jpg" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 2</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras2_min.jpg" alt="The chalet at the Green mountain lake" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras2.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 3</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras3_min.jpg" alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras3.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 4</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras4_min.jpg" alt="On top of Kozi kopka" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras4.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>

    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras_min.jpg" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 2</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras2_min.jpg" alt="The chalet at the Green mountain lake" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras2.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 3</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras3_min.jpg" alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras3.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 4</h5>
      <img src="images/high_tatras4_min.jpg" alt="On top of Kozi kopka" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="images/high_tatras4.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
  </div>

</div>
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/LTC123/pen/JdEMjq)

Comment: You should always include your code in the question itself. Please do not bypass the check by formatting plain text as code block. If code is not added **in the question**, it would be closed without you getting any answers. I have created a Stack Snippet based on the code from CodePen to help you. Also, instead of posting the entire page's code, create a demo with the minimal amount of code that is required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You made some of the float directions wrong. I also think you should reconsider some of the identifier names in your code.

Is this what you were looking for?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpaoaN

```html
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Simple photo manager</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
    #gallery {
      float: left;
      width: 6%;
      min-height: 12em;
    }
    .gallery.custom-state-active {
      background: #eee;
    }
    .gallery li {
      float: left;
      width: 96px;
      padding: 0.4em;
      margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .gallery li h5 {
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
      cursor: move;
    }
    .gallery li a {
      float: right;
    }
    .gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin {
      float: left;
    }
    .gallery li img {
      width: 100%;
      cursor: move;
    }
    #trash {
      float: left;
      width: 80%;
      min-height: 18em;
      padding: 1%;
    }
    #trash h4 {
      line-height: 16px;
      margin: 0 0 0.4em;
    }
    #trash h4 .ui-icon {
      float: left;
    }
    #trash .gallery h5 {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      // there's the gallery and the trash
      var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
        $trash = $("#trash");

      // let the gallery items be draggable
      $("li", $gallery).draggable({
        cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
        revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
        containment: "document",
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "move"
      });

      // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
      $trash.droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          deleteImage(ui.draggable);
        }
      });

      // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
      $gallery.droppable({
        accept: "#trash li",
        activeClass: "custom-state-active",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          recycleImage(ui.draggable);
        }
      });

      // image deletion function
      var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";

      function deleteImage($item) {
        $item.fadeOut(function() {
          var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ?
            $("ul", $trash) :
            $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);

          $item.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
          $item.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
            $item
              .animate({
                width: "48px"
              })
              .find("img")
              .animate({
                height: "36px"
              });
          });
        });
      }

      // image recycle function
      var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";

      function recycleImage($item) {
        $item.fadeOut(function() {
          $item
            .find("a.ui-icon-refresh")
            .remove()
            .end()
            .css("width", "96px")
            .append(trash_icon)
            .find("img")
            .css("height", "72px")
            .end()
            .appendTo($gallery)
            .fadeIn();
        });
      }

      // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
      function viewLargerImage($link) {
        var src = $link.attr("href"),
          title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
          $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");

        if ($modal.length) {
          $modal.dialog("open");
        } else {
          var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
            .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
          setTimeout(function() {
            img.dialog({
              title: title,
              width: 400,
              modal: true
            });
          }, 1);
        }
      }

      // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
      $("ul.gallery > li").click(function(event) {
        var $item = $(this),
          $target = $(event.target);

        if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
          deleteImage($item);
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
          viewLargerImage($target);
        } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
          recycleImage($item);
        }

        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
    <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras_min.jpg" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 2</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras2_min.jpg" alt="The chalet at the Green mountain lake" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras2.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 3</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras3_min.jpg" alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras3.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 4</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras4_min.jpg" alt="On top of Kozi kopka" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras4.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
      <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Trash</span> Trash</h4>
    </div>

    <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix" style="float: right;">
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras_min.jpg" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 2</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras2_min.jpg" alt="The chalet at the Green mountain lake" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras2.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <h5 class="ui-widget-header">High Tatras 3</h5>
        <img src="images/high_tatras3_min.jpg" alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72">
        <a href="images/high_tatras3.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
        <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Actually I wanted it like this. But you helpped a ton. I was wondering how do I make all the images draggable? http://codepen.io/LTC123/pen/PqWemm